# React Native - Detect first time app launch

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I am using React navigation v6 for my react native application. I am stuck at trying to detect if the app is launched for the first time by the user or not.

I have tried to set `FIRST_LAUNCH` through AsyncStorage and then depending on its value I set the `initialRouteName` in the `Stack.Navigator`. This doesn't seem to work as I came to know that `createNativeStackNavigator` is synchronous doesn't wait for the `getItem`'s promise to be fulfilled or rejected to finish up being executed.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    },[]);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Routes />
        </View>
    );
};
```

Routes.js

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Routes(){
    const [firstLaunch , setFirstLaunch] = useState(true);
    
    const checkFirstLaunch = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('FIRST_LAUNCH').then(value => {
            if(value === null){
                AsyncStorage.setItem('FIRST_LAUNCH', 'false');
            }
            setFirstLaunch(false);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        checkFirstLaunch();
        
    }, [])

    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false
                    }}
                    initialRouteName={firstLaunch ? 'Onboarding' : 'TenantHome'}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={OnboardingRoutes} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="TenantHome" component={TenantRoutes} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default Routes;
```

This doesn't seem to work and `firstLaunch` is always true.

I have also read a solution where someone suggested to make a splash screen of my own which is the default first screen and use that to navigate to the onboarding or tenant home screen accordingly. But I already have a splash screen set up by `LaunchScreen.xib` and hiding it using `SplashScreen.hide()` in App.js. Also I don't know if manually creating it is good practice or not.

Can someone help me get about this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try async/await like this:

```
const controlStorage = async () => {
  if (await !AsyncStorage.getItem("FIRST_LAUNCH")) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('FIRST_LAUNCH', 'false');
  }
  setFirstLaunch(false);
}
```

Or:

```
const controlStorage = async () => {
  await AsyncStorage.getItem("FIRST_LAUNCH")) ? setFirstLaunch(false); : AsyncStorage.setItem('FIRST_LAUNCH', 'false'); setFirstLaunch(false);
}
```

And async storage work not like `localStorage`. that's why sometimes a little bit we get confused. We get different data from `asyncstorage`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried what you suggested but nothing changed. Its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `AsyncStorage`, then the below code should work fine:

```
const checkFirstLaunch = async () => {
    const __first_launch = await AsyncStorage.getItem('FIRST_LAUNCH');
    if (!__first_launch) {//This means that no key found with name 'FIRST_LAUNCH' which indicates that the app is launched for the first time
        AsyncStorage.setItem('FIRST_LAUNCH', "Done");//Instead of false try setting value to something like "Done"
        setFirstLaunch(true);//This line is unneccesary as you are setting the default value to true
    } else {//This means that that app is not launched for the first time so we can set setFirstLaunch to false
        setFirstLaunch(false);
    }
}
```

If the above code still does not work, then you can try using `react-native-sqlite-storage`. I know it will increase the complexity of the code but it is much faster than the `AsyncStorage`, so it will also improve the performance of your app.

Check the below code for your reference:

```
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var db = openDatabase({ name: 'YOURAPPDB.db' });

useEffect(() => {
    CreateFirstLaunchTable();//Always remember to create the table first before accessing it
    CheckFirstLaunch();//Checking First Launch in local db
}, []);

const CreateFirstLaunchTable = () => {
    try {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FirstLaunch (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IsFirstLaunch TEXT)'
                , null, (txObj, resultSet) => {
                    console.log('CreateFirstLaunchTable', resultSet);
                }, (txObj, error) => {
                    console.log('FirstLaunch Table Creation Error : ', txObj.message);
                }
            );
        })
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('Table Creation Error: ' + ex);
    }
}

const InsertDataIntoFirstLaunch = () => {
    try {
        db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO FirstLaunch (IsFirstLaunch) values ('Done')", null,
                (txObj, resultSet) => {
                    if (resultSet.rowsAffected == '1') {
                        console.log('Data inserted successfully');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('No Data Insert or updated : ', JSON.stringify(txObj), JSON.stringify(resultSet));
                    }
                },
                (txObj, error) => {
                    console.log('Data Insert/Update Error : ', txObj.message);
                }
            )
        })
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const CheckFirstLaunch = () => {
    try {
        db.transaction(function (txn) {
            txn.executeSql(
                "SELECT * FROM FirstLaunch", null,
                (txObj, resultSet) => {
                    if (resultSet.rows.length == 0) {//It means there is no data in the table which indicates that the app is launched for the first time
                        setFirstLaunch(true);
                    }
                    else {//resultSet.rows.length will always be 1 after 2nd and subsequent launches
                        setFirstLaunch(false);
                        InsertDataIntoFirstLaunch();//Inserting into local db
                    }
                },
                (txObj, error) => {
                    console.log('Getting table details error : ', txObj.message);
                }
            );
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```